# Провести цвет по спектру RGB цветовой диаграммы

Tags: javascript, jquery, математика, графика, color

Задался вопросом как провести цвет формата rgb по всей цветовой диаграмме? Как составить функцию для пересчета номера каждого канала? Приведу пример http://colorscheme.ru/ допустим у нас есть массив из цветов

```css
    .st1{fill: rgb(223,34,89);}
    .st2{fill:rgb(238,82,148);}
    .st3{fill:rgb(178,52,91);}
    .st4{fill:rgb(204,49,113);}
    .st5{fill:rgb(237,62,116);}
    .st6{fill:rgb(173,48,94);}
    .st7{fill:rgb(209,67,119);}
    .st8{fill:rgb(153,27,65);}
    .st9{fill:rgb(213,39,88);}
    .st10{fill:rgb(172,29,69);}
    .st11{fill:rgb(204,55,102);}
    .st12{fill:rgb(136,24,64);}
    .st13{fill:rgb(207,62,115);}
    .st14{fill:rgb(192,36,87);}
    .st15{fill:rgb(150,47,90);}
    .st16{fill:rgb(178,54,98);}
    .st17{fill:rgb(150,42,76);}
    .st18{fill:rgb(178,48,101);}
    .st19{fill:rgb(157,29,80);}
    .st20{fill:rgb(183,55,101);}
    .st21{fill:rgb(186,36,92);}
    .st22{fill:rgb(247,87,145);}
    .st23{fill:rgb(200,35,90);}
    .st25{fill:rgb(242,144,187);}
    .st26{fill:rgb(219,62,120);}
```

Как обойти все эти цвета по кругу диаграммы? Какая зависимость?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "провести цвет .. по всей цветовой диаграмме" ? Что вы понимаете под "функцию для пересчета номера .. канала" ?

Comment: постановка вопроса не верная.. существует множество цветовых моделей и цветовых пространств, которые и определяют формулы и способы получения цветов. Круг о котором Вы говорите, это одно цветовое пространство, а rgb совсем другое, поэтому у Вас не получится из rgb сосздать круг. Для того чтобы понять что нужно делать, нужно прежде всего правильно спросить, а для этого во всем самому разобраться.

Comment: Попробую объяснить на рисунке. ![askMy.png](https://postimg.org/image/wgc8iuzgt/) Вот так у меня есть массив из цветов которые должны одновременно проходить по периметру круга спеткра

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду конвертацию видимого спектра (380нм-780нм) в rgb, то я знаю такую реализацию известной формулы на js:

```
function nmToRGB(wavelength){
    var Gamma = 0.80,
    IntensityMax = 255,
    factor, red, green, blue;
    if((wavelength >= 380) && (wavelength<440)){
        red = -(wavelength - 440) / (440 - 380);
        green = 0.0;
        blue = 1.0;
    }else if((wavelength >= 440) && (wavelength<490)){
        red = 0.0;
        green = (wavelength - 440) / (490 - 440);
        blue = 1.0;
    }else if((wavelength >= 490) && (wavelength<510)){
        red = 0.0;
        green = 1.0;
        blue = -(wavelength - 510) / (510 - 490);
    }else if((wavelength >= 510) && (wavelength<580)){
        red = (wavelength - 510) / (580 - 510);
        green = 1.0;
        blue = 0.0;
    }else if((wavelength >= 580) && (wavelength<645)){
        red = 1.0;
        green = -(wavelength - 645) / (645 - 580);
        blue = 0.0;
    }else if((wavelength >= 645) && (wavelength<781)){
        red = 1.0;
        green = 0.0;
        blue = 0.0;
    }else{
        red = 0.0;
        green = 0.0;
        blue = 0.0;
    };
    // Let the intensity fall off near the vision limits
    if((wavelength >= 380) && (wavelength<420)){
        factor = 0.3 + 0.7*(wavelength - 380) / (420 - 380);
    }else if((wavelength >= 420) && (wavelength<701)){
        factor = 1.0;
    }else if((wavelength >= 701) && (wavelength<781)){
        factor = 0.3 + 0.7*(780 - wavelength) / (780 - 700);
    }else{
        factor = 0.0;
    };
    if (red !== 0){
        red = Math.round(IntensityMax * Math.pow(red * factor, Gamma));
    }
    if (green !== 0){
        green = Math.round(IntensityMax * Math.pow(green * factor, Gamma));
    }
    if (blue !== 0){
        blue = Math.round(IntensityMax * Math.pow(blue * factor, Gamma));
    }
    return [red,green,blue];
}
```

С помощью нее вы сможете пройти весь спектр просто применяя ее для указанного интервала.

Если же вам надо просто обойти все точки внутри rgb. Можно сделать тремя циклами for, например:

```
var r;
var g;
var b;
var maxColor = 255;
var color;

    for(r = 0; r <= maxColor; r++){
      for(g = 0; g <= maxColor; g++){
        for(b = 0; b <= maxColor; b++){
          color = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Меня немного просветили, что я начал не туда копать по данной теме. На самом деле меня интересует функция визуализации HSV https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)